# How to build this query using jena query builder?

Tags: java, sparql, jena, jena-querybuilder

I am trying to construct the below query using the Jena query builder in JAVA. I have tried multiple different ways to build it, but nothing seems to work. Adding values block inside Graph seems to be not possible. Can anyone suggest how this can be done?

We are currently using jena query builder 3.5. Which does not have `WhereBuilder`

```
SELECT ?subject ?predicate ?object ?graph
WHERE {
 
{
  GRAPH <G1> {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
    
      VALUES (?subject ?predicate ?object) {
      (<S1> <P1> <O1>)   
      (<S2> <P2> <O2>)   
      (<S3> <P3> <O3>)   
     }
   
    BIND(<G1> AS ?graph)
  }
}
 
UNION
 
{
  GRAPH <G2 > {
    ?subject ?predicate ?object
    
      VALUES (?subject ?predicate ?object) {
      (<S4> <P4> <O4>)   
      (<S5> <P4> <O5>)   
      (<S6> <P4> <O6>)   
   }
   
    BIND(<G2> AS ?graph)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below :

```
import org.apache.jena.arq.querybuilder.SelectBuilder;
import org.apache.jena.arq.querybuilder.WhereBuilder;
import org.apache.jena.query.Query;

public class JenaQueryBuilderExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SelectBuilder select = new SelectBuilder();   
        
        select.addVar("?subject").addVar("?predicate").addVar("?object").addVar("?graph");
            
        WhereBuilder where1 = new WhereBuilder();    
        
        where1.addGraph("<G1>", graph -> graph.addTriple("?subject", "?predicate", "?object"));  
        
        where1.addValues("?subject ?predicate ?object", "(<S1> <P1> <O1>)", "(<S2> <P2> <O2>)", "(<S3> <P3> <O3>)");    
        
        where1.addBind("<G1>", "?graph");    
        
        WhereBuilder where2 = new WhereBuilder();    
        
        where2.addGraph("<G2>", graph -> graph.addTriple("?subject", "?predicate", "?object"));
            
        where2.addValues("?subject ?predicate ?object", "(<S4> <P4> <O4>)", "(<S5> <P4> <O5>)", "(<S6> <P4> <O6>)");
            
        where2.addBind("<G2>", "?graph");   
        
        select.addUnion(where1, where2);    
        
        Query query = select.build();    
        
        System.out.println(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I missed adding a detail, we are currently using jena query builder 3.5. I am not able to find WhereBuilder  in it. @selaka-nanayakkara

Even the latest version of `WhereBuilder` does not have a method called `addValues` : https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.jena/jena-querybuilder/latest/org/apache/jena/arq/querybuilder/WhereBuilder.html

Comment: Apache Jena 3.5.0 was awhile ago (2017-10-30) and the query builder has advanced since then. Adding values in a `GRAPH` will involve building the pattern such as with another AbstractQueryBuilder. Questions about the query builder can be asked on the Jena users list (subscription and then confirmation required - it reduces unwanted email).